# Chrome Extension: Appending element to popup window instead of browser window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, browser, popup

[image][image]

First picture: Current state,  Second picture: Goal state

Here is my js code(script.js):

In popup.html as well as the manifest file, I include script.js

```
// ... created frameUp, frameDown, frameRight, frameLeft using createElement("DIV")

function addBorder(){
    document.body.appendChild(frameUp);
    document.body.appendChild(frameDown);
    document.body.appendChild(frameRight);
    document.body.appendChild(frameLeft);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = 'click me';
    document.body.appendChild(button);
    button.onclick = addBorder;
    
});
```

Also, I find that when I place code within the addEventListener, every html edit inside it applies to the popup window instead of the entire browser. Which is why I created the button element inside the addEventListener but not the border element. However, **I want to draw a border in the BROWSER rather than the popup every time I press the button.**

How do I change where I appendChild, specifically from the popup window to the browser window? When I use document.body, what is it referring to exactly?

TLDR: Want button in popup but border in browser. Can't figure out how.

Comment: I understand that you are new but you are not asking your question correctly nor are you providing relevant code.
So I'll guess, you're creating an extension for Chrome? If so, what you are editing with JS is popup.html and document.body refers to that file, using code in popup.js or popup.html you cannot modify the current web page where your extension is running.

Comment: create a new file called script.js and add it to your manifest.json `"content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "<all_urls>"
          ],
          "js": ["script.js"]
        }
      ]`

Comment: inside script.js is that you are going to create your logic to add those borders and that button.
By the way, what the code fragment I passed does is so that script.js is executed when your extension is loaded.

Comment: So sorry for my unclear wording, I'll make edits to the post now! But I'm confused on what you mean by "using code in popup.js or popup.html you cannot modify the current webpage" If you see my second screenshot, I was actually able to edit the webpage using my unpacked chrome extension, as long as I call the addBorder function outside of the addEventListener. The second screenshot was a previous version without the inclusion of the button. I should have mentioned that, I'm sorry.

Comment: What about inserting a div element with style? <div style="border: 20px blue solid; position:fixed; top:0; right:0; left:0; bottom:0;"></div>

Comment: What is supposed to contain "frameUp" and the rest of the values?

Comment: There are many questions about your problem haha...
You must show more code
What is the name of the file where you have that code that you shared?

Comment: @Rafael Dorado While making the border, I realized that overlaying a transparent rectangle with solid border on top of the browser wouldn't work since it would prevent me from clicking anything inside the rectangle. So instead, I made four lines: frameUp, frameDown... to look like a border.  I think your question is exactly what I'm confused about. Why was it that I was able to overlay frameUp, frameDown, etc. onto the browser with document.body.appendChild()? Where exactly am I appending to? How do I specify that I don't want to append to popup.html but the browser specifically?

Comment: Once again I repeat, the code you shared is making changes to popup.html and not to the web page where your extension is executed. I told you to make a file called "script.js" so that from popup.js you can send a message to script.js to modify the document of the web page, but not before adding what I told you in the manifest. In fact, I just did what you want and it didn't take me more than 2 minutes.

Comment: Ohh! So I need two js files, one for the popup(containing the button) and one for the webpage(script.js)? In the manifest, only add script.js? But in popup.html, include popup.js? Thank you so much for your time to answer my questions, sorry I kept getting confused.

Comment: I have published it as an answer so that you follow step by step, you only have to create 4 files and add it to chrome so you can see that it works, and then you adapt that to your project, I suggest that you make a new folder for the test.

Answer (score 0):

Declare permissions:

Make sure that the extension's manifest.json file declares the permissions required to access web pages. You can add something like this:

```
{
"name": "My Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions": ["activeTab", "storage", "webNavigation"],
"browser_action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
]
}
```

Popup HTML (popup.html):

Create the button and add popup.js to send the message to content.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My Extension</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <button id="editButton">Edit document.body</button>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Popup JavaScript (popup.js):

Add logic to the popup script to send a message to the content script when the button is clicked.

```
document.getElementById('editButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
 chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) 
 {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'editBody' });
 });
});
```

Handle message in content script:

In the content script (content.js), you must handle the message and perform the necessary manipulation.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
 if (request.action === 'editBody') {
   // edit document.body
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
 }
});
```